# Using topology to connect nodes <100m apart only

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, topology

I have a bunch of line segments, most of which have gaps that are 100m or less.
What I'm trying to do is connect these gaps so I have a series of connected line segments BUT leave nodes that are over 100m distance. Reason for this is each series of lines are to be grouped separately.

Here's an example of one section....
[image]

I've been trying to do this through topology editing (*must not have dangles*) but can't seem to find where I can set a max distance of 100m between nodes before connecting. It keeps wanting to connect what all the nodes. Is this possible or is there some other way?
I'm using ArcMap10 with Advanced license

Comment: You can try Integrate to snap the ends together but that will also snap lines together. Try exporting the nodes, find the ones that are far apart using Generate Near Table and add these into the topology with a high rank then remove later after the other ends are snapped.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a standard or and advanced licence, you can use [Snap(editing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000) or [extend(editing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extend_Line/001v00000004000000/) to fill your gaps. The difference between the two is that extend does not change the direction of your segments.

This will give you more control of what you are doing (including maximum distance) than the integrate tool (which is available with any type of licence). Note that, as for any editing tool, it is recommended to use them in an edit session or on a copy of your data, because the file itself is modified.